# Варнинг телеграм бота/парсера о незакрытой сессии

Tags: python, telebot, asyncio, aiohttp

Как избавиться от данного варнинга?

**Варнинг:**

```
Unclosed client session

client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000023A0B07EA90>

Unclosed connector connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x0000023A098957F0>, 1732752.765)]']

connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x0000023A0AFBFDD0>
```

**Код:**

```
import asyncio
import feedparser
from aiogram import Bot
import aiohttp
import aiosqlite

async def run_in_executor(session, channels):
    entries = []
    for url, title in channels.items():
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            feed = await resp.text()
        feed = feedparser.parse(feed)
        for entry in feed.entries:
            entry.title = f"{title}\n{entry.title}"  # Добавляем заголовок перед заголовком новости
            entries.append(entry)
    return entries

async def post_news_to_channel(bot_token, channel_id, news, start_date):
    bot = Bot(token=bot_token)
    for entry in news:
        # Проверяем, была ли уже опубликована данная новость и дата новости больше указанной start_date
        if entry.link not in await get_published_news() and entry.published_parsed >= start_date:
            message = f"\n{entry.title}\n{entry.link}"
            try:
                await bot.send_message(chat_id=channel_id, text=message, parse_mode='Markdown')
                await save_published_news(entry.link)  # Сохраняем новость в базу данных
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Failed to post news: {e}")
    await bot.closed()

async def update_news():
    rss_channels = {}

    bot_token = ""
    channel_id = ""

    start_date = (2023, 7, 4, 15, 00, 0, 0, 0, 0)  # Указываем начальную дату публикации новостей (год, месяц, день, час, минута, секунда)

    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
        try:
            news = await run_in_executor(session, rss_channels)
            await post_news_to_channel(bot_token, channel_id, news, start_date)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to update news: {e}")
        await session.close()
        await connector.close()

async def initialize_database():
    async with aiosqlite.connect('newskz.db') as db:
        await db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS published_news
                 (link TEXT PRIMARY KEY)''')
        await db.commit()

async def get_published_news():
    async with aiosqlite.connect('newskz.db') as db:
        cursor = await db.execute("SELECT link FROM published_news")
        published_news = [row[0] for row in await cursor.fetchall()]
    return published_news

async def save_published_news(link):
    async with aiosqlite.connect('newskz.db') as db:
        await db.execute("INSERT INTO published_news (link) VALUES (?)", (link,))
        await db.commit()

async def main():
    await initialize_database() # Инициализация базы данных
    while True:
        await update_news()
        await asyncio.sleep(5 * 60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```